# Dynamics CRM : Retrieve multiple appointments for a systemuser

Tags: c#, soap, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm a trying to get all the appointments for a systemuser with a RetrieveMultiple method and a query expression. Example :

```
WhoAmIRequest userRequest = new WhoAmIRequest();
WhoAmIResponse userResponse = (WhoAmIResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(userRequest);

QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
qe.EntityName = "systemuser";

...
slos.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
```

Can I retrieve all the appointments of a systemuser (owner, organizer, required attendee, optional attendee) from a systemuser entity ?

Or do I have to retrieve all the appointments of the CRM and add conditions to know if the user is owner, organizer, required or optional attendee ?

Finally, I'm using SOAP Logger, is it the best way to generate SOAP request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the relationship entity `activitypointer` between `appointment` and `systemuser`. As you'll see in my examples, this makes things a little complicated.

There are at least 2 possible ways to build your desired query:

1) As you already figured, you can filter appointments by systemuserid:

```
var qe = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "appointment",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("subject"),
    LinkEntities =
    {
        new LinkEntity
        {
            EntityAlias = "ap",
            JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
            Columns = new ColumnSet(false),
            LinkFromEntityName = "appointment",
            LinkFromAttributeName = "activityid",
            LinkToEntityName = "activityparty",
            LinkToAttributeName = "activityid",
            LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression
            {
                Conditions =
                {
                    new ConditionExpression("partyid", ConditionOperator.Equal, userid),
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
```

2) You can query the systemuser by systemuserid and add the appointments as a linked entity (like a JOIN in a sql query):

```
var qe2 = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "systemuser",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(false),
    LinkEntities =
    {
        new LinkEntity
        {
            EntityAlias = "ap",
            Columns = new ColumnSet(false),
            JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
            LinkFromEntityName = "systemuser",
            LinkFromAttributeName = "systemuserid",
            LinkToEntityName = "activityparty",
            LinkToAttributeName = "partyid",
            LinkEntities =
            {
                new LinkEntity
                {
                    EntityAlias = "a",
                    Columns = new ColumnSet("subject"),
                    JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
                    LinkFromEntityName = "activityparty",
                    LinkFromAttributeName = "activityid",
                    LinkToEntityName = "appointment",
                    LinkToAttributeName = "activityid",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    Criteria = new FilterExpression
    {
        Conditions =
        {
            new ConditionExpression("systemuserid", ConditionOperator.Equal, userid),
        },
    },
};
```

Concerning the filter for the participation role, you'll have to add a condition on the `participationtypemask` on the `activitypointer`:

```
// user is Organizer, Owner, required or optional Attendee
ConditionExpression("participationtypemask", ConditionOperator.In, new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 9 }),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it saves my day. One more thing, if a set "organizer" in ColumnSet, it retrieve an EntityCollection with all the fields. Is it possible to specify which fields that I want in organizer ?

Comment: Of course this is possible - instead of just specifying *"subject"* as in my expample, you can simply set `new ColumnSet(true)` which will retrieve all fields. If you need to construct your QueryExpression based on conditions, just take it apart and set the the properties as needed. I tend to construct QueryExpression in the way shown because imho it makes them more readable the way sql queries are.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't phrase my question well. If a add organizer in my ColumnSet, it retrieves the organizer but with all the fields attached to organizer. What I wanted to do is to have only specific fields into organizer. I don't know if it's clear ?

Comment: If you need details about your *systemuser*, you'll either have to use example 2 and change `new ColumnSet(false)` to `new ColumnSet(true)` or add the `systemuser`entity as a LinkEntity below the `activitypointer`. In either case, you'll have to deal with `AliasedValue` from your LinkEntity fields.

Answer (score 0):

With this Expression, I don't receive any appointments now :

```
QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "appointment",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("activityid", "subject", "scheduledstart", "scheduledend", "location", "description"),
    Criteria = new FilterExpression
    {
        FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
        Conditions = 
        {
            new ConditionExpression("scheduledend", ConditionOperator.GreaterThan, startTime),
            new ConditionExpression("scheduledstart", ConditionOperator.LessThan, endTime)
         }
     },
     LinkEntities = 
     {
         new LinkEntity
         {
             LinkFromEntityName = "activitypointer",
             LinkFromAttributeName = "activityid",
             LinkToEntityName = "activityparty",
             LinkToAttributeName = "activityid",
             LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression
             {
                 FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                 Conditions = 
                 {
                     new ConditionExpression("participationtypemask", ConditionOperator.In, new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 9 }),
                     new ConditionExpression("partyid", ConditionOperator.Equal, userResponse.UserId)

                 }
             }
         },
         new LinkEntity
         {
             EntityAlias = "requiredattendees",
             Columns = new ColumnSet(false),
             JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
             LinkFromEntityName = "activitypointer",
             LinkFromAttributeName = "activityid",
             LinkToEntityName = "activityparty",
             LinkToAttributeName = "activityid",
             LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression
             {
                 Conditions = 
                 {
                     new ConditionExpression("participationtypemask", ConditionOperator.Equal, 5)

                 }
             },
             LinkEntities =
             {
                 new LinkEntity
                 {
                     EntityAlias = "contact",
                     Columns = new ColumnSet("fullname"),
                     JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
                     LinkFromEntityName = "activityparty",
                     LinkFromAttributeName = "activityid",
                     LinkToEntityName = "contact",
                     LinkToAttributeName = "contactid"
                 },
             }
         }
     }
 };

 qe.Distinct = true;

 slos.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
```

Comment: At first glance I'd say your problem is now that you specify `JoinOperator.Inner` on both your *requiredattendees* and *contact* LinkEntities (should be JoinOperator.LeftOuter). If I find myself with unexpected results like this, I try rebuilding the query using "Advanced Find" and inspect the FetchXml behind it. This usually clear up things pretty fast. Side note: You may want to move the content of this "answer" to your original post or post as a new question.